# React TS - Type '() => Promise<void>' is not assignable to type 'EventHandler<ClickEvent, boolean | void>'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a component, that has `onClick` prop.

I'm passing it an async handler, and getting the error:

> Type '() => Promise' is not assignable to type 'EventHandler<ClickEvent, boolean | void>'.
> Type 'Promise' is not assignable to type 'boolean | void'.
> Type 'Promise' is not assignable to type 'void'.ts(2322)

**Code**

```
onClick={async () => {
        await item.onClick();
        menuRenderParams.closeMenu();
      }}
```

I tried using named handler `_onClick`, and specify the return type, but it didn't work.

While using the named handler I tried give the handler type like this: `_onClick: EventHandler` but got this error:

> Generic type 'EventHandler' requires 1 type argument(s).

I look around for typescript promise handler type but didn't found anything.

- side note, I added `"strict": false` to the .tsconfig, but the compilation still fails. if you could help me understand this also it would be gr8.

Answer (score 0):

This is gonna work fine i think your type is incorrect.

take a look at this code:

```
type SomeFunc = () => Promise<string>

const func: SomeFunc = () => {
  return new Promise<string>((resolve, reject) => resolve("someinfo"));
};


<div
  onClick={async (event: MouseEvent) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const result = await func();
    console.log(result);
  }}
></div>
```

it works fine please share your type here.
make sure you have imported `MouseEvent` type from react

Comment: getting this error now: 
Type '(event: MouseEvent) => Promise<void>' is not assignable to type 'EventHandler<ClickEvent, boolean | void>'.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/9608006/itay-tur Show me your component and type file